# \leftrightarrow renders differently from Lamports' book

Tags: math-mode

I am currently looking at Lamport's "document preparation system for LaTeX" (1994 edition) and I am surprised to see that some of the mathematical symbols are rendered differently in the book than when I use them in a document. For instance, \leftrightarrow (page 43) has shorters arrow heads in the book. I'm just curious : has something changed in the rendering of these symbols ?

Thank you !

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} \begin{document} $\leftrightarrow$ \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what code are you using now? even if you are using cm fonts you will be using type1 versions not the metfaont version (I think Lamport's book used cm)

Comment: I am using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex). I don'k know how to find which fonts are used, but I understand your comment and your answer makes sense to me, thank you !

Comment: the fonts used depend on the commands in your document not the pdftex version. You should be able to show a small one line document that has the arrow that you are asking about

Comment: OK, I am using
`\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
$\leftrightarrow$
\end{document}`

Comment: ok that is a computer modern arrow

Comment: I have a vague recollection that at some point Knuth modified the arrowheads in CM at some point (I think around the time that he also made some changes to, iirc, δ, but I've been unable to find the information on this. Certainly, it wouldn't surprise me if a 1994 printing had the older version of the fonts assuming I'm correct.

Comment: @DonHosek I had a similar thought, I guess Leslie's book wouldn't have been using the am fonts  by the 1994 editon.

Comment: Richard I don't have the book to hand could you upload an image of the arrow from the book?

Comment: @DonHosek https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/cm.html  "Many characters were improved in 1992, notably the arrows"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computer modern fonts were updated in 1992 with arrows in particular being updated, see D. Knuth's message

[https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/cm.html](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/cm.html)

> Many characters were improved in 1992, notably the arrows

The 1994 edition of The LaTeX book was still using the older versions.

---

Campa points out that the older arrow forms have been preserved in a font made available by the `old-arrows` package so

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{old-arrows}
\begin{document} $\leftrightarrow$ \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to mention the package `old-arrows`. Personally, I find the old arrowheads better (and they harmonize better with the ones by `amsfonts`); I always wondered whether the change was related to the printer capabilities of those times.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what happened, I checked the rendering of \delta as advised and indeed, the version of Lamport's book I am looking at is using the older version.

Comment: @campa never noticed that package before, but done thanks